# Edit and replace partial URLs in tumblr posts

Tags: python, url, tumblr, autohotkey

I want to change my URL in tumblr but I have hardcoded links to my blog all over the place. Rather than go into over 1000 posts and manually update the links, I was told it can be automated. I'd need it to:

1. Visit a page of the blog
2. Check for the old URL within the hyperlinked text of the post
3. If present, click Edit to edit the post content
4. Click the URL in the text area
5. Click Edit in the popup that'll appear
6. Replace only part of the URL in the popup with the new URL (ex: if we start with http://old.tumblr.com/tagged we'd then want http://new.tumblr.com/tagged)
7. Click Done on the popup to close it and save URL changes
8. Save changes to the post
9. Proceed to check the next post on the page
10. If no more instances occur, continue to the next page
11. Repeat until last page is reached

So I believe I understand the logic/steps required, but my flaw is in being able to execute them. What would be the best language or method to go about implementing this? Something straight-forward preferred, as I'm a complete coding newbie. Python was mentioned to me. Autohotkey maybe, as well?

My apologies if this isn't the correct place to ask.

Currently I've got a redirect in place on the old URL's page.

```html
<title>Redirect</title>
<script>location.replace('http://new.tumblr.com' + location.pathname);</script>
<noscript>
<h1>This blog has moved to <a href="http://new.tumblr.com/">New Blog</a>.</h1>
<p>If you&rsquo;re reading this, you have JavaScript turned off and therefore can&rsquo;t be redirected automatically. Replace &ldquo;{BlogURL}&rdquo; with &ldquo;http://{text:New Tumblr URL}.tumblr.com/&rdquo; in your browser&rsquo;s address bar to get to your destination.</p>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Right now I've got a redirect in place on the old URL's page

Comment: @mikedidthis -I added the redirect code I'm using to the above post. It gets the job done, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well in AutoHotkey I'd use IE COM Automation to get the job done, it'd be the most reliable.

[Com Object Reference](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?p=484#p484)

Edit:

Frankly editing HTML using browser automation methods is just a terribly inefficient way to go about this. If you have a access to the site, you likely have access to Upload HTML files directly. If this is the case, the code below should provide you enough details about how to edit the links contained within your pages.

The code below is simplification of what you'll be doing. Just to familiarize yourself with the process.

```
html =
(
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://old.tumblr.com/tagged1"/>this old link</a>
<a href="http://old.tumblr.com/tagged2"/>this old link two</a>
<a href="http://old.tumblr.com/tagged3"/>this old link three</a>
<a href="http://new.tumblr.com/tagged3"/>this new link</a>
</body>
</html>
)

pwb := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile"), pwb.Write( html )
Links := pwb.Links
Loop % Links.Length ; check each link
        If ((RelatedLink := Links[A_Index-1].href) != "" && (Links[A_Index-1].href ~= "http://old.")) { ; if the link is not blank
               Links[A_Index-1].href := StrReplace(Links[A_Index-1].href, "http://old.", "http://new.")
            }

html := pwb.documentElement.innerHTML
MsgBox % html
```

And this is how I would go about applying it to a bunch of websites:

```
SetBatchLines -1
fileName := A_ScriptDir . "\myfile.txt"

MyListOfWebPages = ; add all your blog page urls here
(
http://myblogpageone.html
http://myblogpagetwo.html
http://myblogpagethree.html
http://myblogpagefour.html
)

For Each, Line in StrSplit(MyListOfWebPages, "`n", "`r") {
          FileAppend, % GrabWebPage(Line), % A_scriptDir "\htmlfile" A_index ".html"
}

GrabWebPage(Webpage) {
whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
;Change below to your URL
whr.Open("GET", Webpage, true) 
whr.Send()
whr.WaitForResponse()
pwb := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile"), pwb.Write( whr.ResponseText ) 

Links := pwb.Links ; collection of hyperlinks on the page
   Loop % Links.Length ; check each link
        If ((RelatedLink := Links[A_Index-1].href) != "" && (Links[A_Index-1].href ~= "http://old.")) { ; if the link is not blank
               Links[A_Index-1].href := StrReplace(Links[A_Index-1].href, "http://old.", "http://new.")
            }
    Return pwb.documentElement.innerHTML
}
```

Comment: I will check into that. Thank you!